# Delete a network profile from wpa_supplicant.conf in Linux (raspbian).

Tags: linux, sed, awk, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm runnining Raspbian, but this is not a Pi specific question

I need to delete *from within my C program* an unused network profile from etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.

My program runs as root.

Is there a shell command for this ?

I tried using combinations of grep, tr, and sed, but I'm not getting quite there.
Also the white-spaces may vary.

I need to remove this block for a given ssid, disregarding white-spaces.

```
   network={
      ssid="MY_SSID_TO_DELETE"
      .........
   }
```

Comment: You can probably get it done with `sed`; but agree, there ought to be a utility for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SSID_TO_DELETE="Put your ssid here"
sed -n "1 !H;1 h;$ {x;s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid=\"${SSID_TO_DELETE}\"[^}]*}//g;p;}" YourFile
```

in a C that can generate your SSID info directly in command (replace Put_your_ssid_here with the value of the ssid)

```
sed '1 !H;1 h;$ {x;s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid="Put_your_ssid_here"[^}]*}//g;}' YourFile
```

1st snippet with \n in place of ;

```
SSID_TO_DELETE="Put your ssid here"
    sed -n "1 !H
       1 h
       $ {
         x
         s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid=\"${SSID_TO_DELETE}\"[^}]*}//g
         p
         }" YourFile
```

Principle (based on last snippet)

- sed -n: don't print line when read (unless specific request in code)
- 1 !H and 1 h load all the lines into the the hold buffer (so all the file is in memory, sed work by default line by line)
- $ mean when last line is reach
- x, load hold buffer (the load file) into working buffer (the one sed can work on)
- s/... replace the part of text containing your network pattern until first } after your SSID on next line by nothing (g: for all occurence)
- p print the final result

Comment: Hi, I tried the 1st code snippet above I get this message             ` -bash: !H: event not found`

Comment: The 2nd code snippet 'sort-of' works.  The file contents before deletion and after, both print on the screen.  If we could only get the latter (deleted version)  to print, it would be perfect !

Comment: try sed -n and change g;} with g;p;} at the end. FOr the snippet, i change and add a space (missing at copy) after the 2 first 1 of the sed

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your replies ! Sorry for the delayed response...was a bit busy over the weekend... The 2nd code works now ! (I'll test it a bit more) ...   the 1st code still gives  -bash: !H: event not found` even after the edits you suggested ... I did not understand your instruction about adding the space ... where to add ?    Also in the 1st code, the sed parameters are enclosed in " , while in the 2nd code they are enclosed in '. - is this OK ?   It would be great if the 1st code could work as well, so I can add it in a script and then pass the ssid to it. Thank You !

Comment: i just adapat the 1st snippet and test it here (AIX and KSH). No error occuring and display the good result. Do you still have the problem ?

Comment: Yes, in the modified 1st code, i'm still getting : -bash: !H: event not found ... anything I need to check ? What _event_ does it expect ? Perhaps I could give you more information ? Thanks !

Comment: try replace the ; by a carriage return (new line) after H and h

Comment: You mean like this ? ........      SSID_TO_DELETE="TRIMURTI"
sed -n "1 !H\n1 h\n$ {x;s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid=\"${SSID_TO_DELETE}\"[^}]*}//g;p;}" wpa.txt

Comment: no probleme, no not a \n a real CR (i will add a 3th snippet wit it)

Comment: Neron, sorry I caused you needless trouble :P ! The original code(1st) works fine inside a bash script! I was trying it from the prompt (where it failed), since the 2nd worked from the prompt! I got the clue when I saw the modified code with the 'enter's. So it had to be inside a script ! It seems to work now (still checking). The modified code (with the 'Enter's is not needed ;) **Many Thanks!** Could you  briefly explain how the code(s) work (if you have the time)? Thanks again ! I will marking this as 'Top Answer' shortly after I test the code a bit (right now I'm using a dummy file) :)

Comment: i will add the explaination in answer directly

Comment: So there is no difference between Code snippets 1 & 3, right? Both are identical ?

Comment: for the algorythm your are right, same code. For interpretation by sed it's the same normaly, just the new line instead of ";". This is mainly due to some different interpretation by sed depending of OS version and sed version. By example, some GNU linux sed accept a ";t a;" and the same doesn't work on my AIX/KSH/sed where same "t a" with new line before and after works

Comment: Hi Neron, I have a request ... could you isolate the part of your code that isolates the desired 'network= { ... } block, given the SSID ?   .My code has progressed, thanks to you, but a bit slowly, as it is more of a hobby. I need a way to to do other things from my code, like change the passkey, etc.      .So if I can ouput the relevant 'network= { ... }' block by passing the SSID, I can try a couple of things on my own .... Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by isolate (extend you question with a sample maybe)

Comment: Hi, Neron, sorry for the delayed response, what i need is: (1) if I pass the SSID name to my script, it should just ouput the block relevant to that SSID i.e.: "network={ .... }" for the given SSID. (2)  I also would like to replace the WiFi password from my program by passing the SSID & new password to the script.  PS: Is it okay to ask these things here, or would you like me to open another topic ? Thank You !

Comment: make some try and post a new question with your test if you could not find the solution. The principle of the site does not provide code for a problem but to help on a unresolved problem you have ;-)

Comment: Hi Neron, as you suggested I tried something with my new knowledge of sed. I posted a new question here, with what i've tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215830/change-wifi-wpa2-passkey-from-a-script      would you be kind enough to take a look ? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SSID_TO_DELETE=$1
    sudo sed -n "1 !H
       1 h
       $ {
         x
         s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid=\"${SSID_TO_DELETE}\"[^}]*}//g
         p
         }" /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```