# Change WiFi WPA2 passkey from a script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspbian Wheezy, but this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question.

I am developing a C application, which allows the user to change their WiFi Password.

I did not find a ready script/command for this, so I'm trying to use *sed*.

I pass the SSID name and new key to a bash script, and the key is replaced for the that ssid block within *etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.*.

My application runs as root.

A sample block is shown below.

```
    network={
        ssid="MY_SSID"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="my_ssid_psk"
}
```

so far I've tried the following (I've copied the wpa_supplicant.conf to wpa.txt for trying) :

(1) This tries to do the replacement between a range, started when my SSID is detected, and ending when the closing brace, followed by a newline.

```
SSID="TRIMURTI"
PSK="12345678"

sed -n "1 !H;1 h;$ {x;/ssid=\"${SSID}\"/,/}\n/ s/[[:space:]]*psk=.*\n/\n   psk=\"${PSK}\"\n/p;}" wpa.txt
```

and

(2) This tries to 'remember' the matched pattern, and reproduce it in the output, but with the new key.

```
SSID="TRIMURTI"
PSK="12345678"

sed -n "1 !H; 1 h;$ {x;s/\(ssid=\"${SSID}\".*psk=\).*\n/\1\"${PSK}\"/p;}" wpa.txt
```

I have used hold & pattern buffers as the pattern can span multiple lines.

Above, the first example seems to ignore the range & replaces the 1st instance, and then truncates the rest of the file.

The second example replaces the last found psk value & truncates the file thereafter.

So I need help in correcting the above code, or trying a different solution.

Comment: I guess your code may still work, but for correctness sake, change `sed -n "1 !H; 1 h;$...` to `sed -n "1 !H; 1 h;\$...`

Comment: `sed` is problematic here because you basically disallow whichever character you are using as the regex delimiter. There are ways around that, but maybe you should consider switching to a tool where code and data are not intermixed?

Comment: Please help.    I'm looking for a way to change the WiFi WPA2 Passkey via a script. Has nobody tried this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume the fields will always be in a strict order where the `ssid=` goes before `psk=`, all you really need is

```
 sed "/^[[:space:]]*ssid=\"$SSID\"[[:space:]]*$/,/}/s/^\([[:space:]]*psk=\"\)[^\"]*/\1$PSK/" wpa.txt
```

This is fairly brittle, though.  If the input is malformed, or if the `ssid` goes after the `psk` in your block, it will break.  The proper solution (which however is severe overkill in this case) is to have a proper parser for the input format; while that is in theory possible in `sed`, it would be much simpler if you were to swtich a higher-level language like Python or Perl, or even Awk.

Comment: Thank you, triplee, i get the following errors:      ./chPSK.sh: line 18: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./chPSK.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Where, chPSK.sh is my script file, and your sed code is on line 18.

Comment: OK, I corrected your code. [^"] should be [^\"]       .Also, you forgot the closing brace before the final "   .(Actually, the braces are not required here) ...   ;-)Now it works.    .Let me test it for a bit ... **Thank you** for putting me on the right direction :-).   Maybe you should edit your code for me to mark it as Answer ?

Comment: Thanks , I got interrupted and didn't have time to test. :-/

Comment: Just a note ... you need to add a closing brace before the last ".   **Thank you** for your help !

Comment: Or remove the stray opening brace. Updated now. Thanks for your persistence (-:

Answer (score 0):

The most useful case is update a password or other value in configuration is to utilize wpa_cli. E.g.:

```
wpa_cli -i "wlan0" set_network "0" psk "\"Some5Strong1Pass"\"
wpa_cli -i "wlan0" save_config
```

The `save_config` method is required to update cfg file: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`